# How to extract constructor's parameter from a class where it's being created/ Called ? - C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am calling a class (Usercontrol) by passing some parameters in its constructor. I'm also saving class instance in a list to perform some custom operations..

```
// In a Main Class
private List<Point> _pList= new List<Point>(); // Point is a UserControl

private void function(header, tx, rx) 
{
Point pt= new Point(header, tx, rx); // all parameters are string and values are dynamic for each class instance

// some operations

_pList.add(pt);
}
```

In Somewhere in the same class I want to access some special instance of class by checking its parameters. But I don't know how to extract parameters of class by it's instance.
 Here is a Pseudo-Code what I want

```
foreach(var pt in _pList)
{
string header= "something";
string tx = "tx1";
string rx = "rx1";

if(pt.parameter[1]=header && .... ) // just a Pseudo-Code
{
// some tasks
}
```

}

Kindly guide me how to achieve this.. Thank You

Comment: What exactly is the `Point` class? Are you able to modify it? You could just save those values in the constructor and expose them as read-only properties.If you can't, save them in the [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_FrameworkElement_Tag).

Comment: If you need to get at these parameter values then they should be public properties. Perhaps dependency properties. There's already a thing called a Point. I suggest you try to use unique names for your classes.  I guess you're not using mvvm here - if not then you should take a look at the pattern if you're going to do much wpf development.

Comment: Thanks @Andy really useful suggestion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your Point looks -

```
public class Point
{
   public string Header{get;set;}
   public string Tx {get;set;}
   public string Rx  {get;set;}

   Public Point(string header,string tx,string rx)
   {
       Header=header;
       Tx=tx;
       Rx=rx;
   }
}
```

Your code remain the same of creating the objects and adding it to list.

From your Pseudo-Code, update this to -

```
foreach(var pt in _pList)
{
string header= "something";
string tx = "tx1";
string rx = "rx1";

if(pt.Header==header && pt.Tx==tx && pt.Rx==rx) // just a Pseudo-Code
{
// some tasks
}
```

Above is simple change you can make to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Although it suggest your are doing something fishy... as a last resort, you can store them at a place you can access them.

e.g:

```
public class PointContainer
{
    public Point point {get;set;}
    public string header {get;set;}
    public string tx{get;set;}
    //etc
}
```

And use it in your list:

```
//first create the container:
var pc = new PointContainer() { /* initialize variables */ };
//and put it in your list
_pList.Add(pc);
//your will contain the combination of points and parameters
```

---

Normally, you would be able to gain access to the variables you passed through the object itself:

```
var point = new Point(header);
var header = point.Header; //so in your case this public property seems missing
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Both approaches are fine... But I'm taking the other one..
Really Thanks for the useful Answer :)